A Geometry question from STEMS (by CMI) of year 2020
The Question is:
In triangle ABC, the incircle ω touches sides BC, CA, AB at D, E, F respectively. Let P be the foot of perpendicular from D to EF. Let AB = 13, BC = 14, CA = 15.
Determine BP : PC.


Now I tried to make the incenter and then join it with vertices A, B, C but got stuck there, then I tried to find the length of EF but couldnt find a normal way (there may be some special constructions which leads to length of EF) Thought of Similar Triangles, but there were no parallel lines.
And Got stuck in this problem, please help if you can

HINT.-The true shape of the triangle appears in the attached figure.

The triangle has vertex $A=(5,12),B=(0,0),c=(14,0)$ which leads to the points $D=(6,0), E=(9.2,6.4), F=\left(\dfrac{30}{13},\dfrac{72}{13}\right)$ after the well known and easy determination of the incenter $I=(6,4)$

The perpendicular to the line $\overline{FE}$ from the point $D$ determines the intersection point $P$ whose coordinates are easily calculated. You have
$P=\left(\dfrac{342}{65},\dfrac{384}{65}\right)$


You finally have the triangle $\triangle{BPC}$ where you can determine the properties you want, in particular $BP:PC$


Which website did you used for making this diagram please tell

@Name not Allowed: Using DESMOS but with personal calculations you get the attached figure.

Could you please share any insights or approaches you might have for solving this problem using Euclidean geometry?

I see you are a student. I explicit more the calculation. You have side $BC$ of lenght $14$. For find out the vertex $A$ you form the circles $x^2+y^2=13^2$ and  $(x-14)^2+y^2=15^2$ so $A$ is the intersection of these circles. Is this way i have determined that $A=(5,12)$. Other results come from your knowledge , DESMOS simply  obey your instructions.

@Name not Allowed: I don't know a direct way to solve your problem by Euclidean geometry. Thinking about it, certainly you could solve it but you need time.

Thank you for your help and for introducing me to this method of graphing using Desmos. I truly appreciate your guidance and support.

You're welcome. It's a pleasure for me to teach a student some math.


Accurate drawing shows that:
$BD=6$
$DC=8$
$\Rightarrow \frac {PB}{PC}=\frac{BD=6}{DC=8}=0.75$
1- the picture shows that:
$1:$ $\angle PBA=\angle PCA $
$2:$ Using formula:
$a^2=b^2+c^2-2 BC\cdot Cos BAC$
and the measure of a, b and c we find:
$\angle BAC=60^o\Rightarrow \angle AEF=\angle AFE=60^o\Rightarrow \angle BEP=\angle CFP=120^o$
That is triangles BEP and CFP are similar and we may write:
$\frac{PB}{PC}=\frac{BE=6}{CF=8}=0.75$
2- The measures of BE, CF,  BD and CD  can be calculated using the measure of the in radius $r$ and the measures of angle of triangle ABC:
$r=\sqrt{\frac{(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}p}$
where $p=\frac{a+b+c}2$
$BD=\frac r{tan \frac {\widehat {ABC}}2}$
$BD=\frac r{tan \frac {\widehat {ACB}}2}$

This seems dubious to me. How do you know that "PD is equal to half of AT", but subsequently show that $PD = 12.09\ldots$ while claiming $AT = 6$?  $\quad$ Are you claiming a proof by accurate diagram? IE How do we know that "The picture shows that $\angle PBA = \angle PCA$?

This is one of those questions where they were disguising a proof-based question by obscuring it with numbers. Honestly, in a contest setting where only numerical answers are required, I would just coordinate geom it.
I ultimately used similar triangles, but the setup isn't obvious.
Using Wishful thinking, let's backtrack and make guesses about what we are supposed to show.

$BP, PC$ seem quite random, how is $P$ related to $B, C$?

Let's avoid $BP, CP$ as much as possible, and relate them to other things instead.


If $PD$ is the angle bisector of $BPC$, then $BP:PC = BD : DC$.

This seems to be the main reasonable way to relate $BP:PC$.
As it turns out, this is the disguised proof-based question that I was referring to. From the conditions, we can calculate $BD = 6, DC = 8$ so the desired ratio is $\boxed{3:4}$. Henceforth, we don't need the specific values of the lengths.


How can we relate $\angle BPD = \angle CPD$ to anything else?

It is equivalent to show that $ \angle FPB = \angle EPC$, so would that be a viable alternative?
It would be natural to consider triangle $FPB, EPC$. Since $\angle PFB = \angle PEC$, it seems like we need to show that they are similar. Angle chasing doesn't seem to help (since $P$ seems quite random in relation to $B, C$), so let's chase down side lengths.


Use the fact that $ PD \perp EF \perp$ angle bisector at $A$ to show that $\angle PDE = \gamma/2 $.

Hence, show that $FP : PE = BD : DC$
Interesting that this ratio comes into play again. Can we exploit $ FP : PE = BD : DC = BF : CE$.
Triangles $PFB, PEC$  are similar by SAS as desired



Now, write the solution up in the forward direction.
